# Find instance of IDocumentSetupParticipant

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm working on an eclipse plugin and added a `documentSetup` extension. How can I obtain the instance of that class in the running eclipse instance in my unit tests?

**plugin.xml**

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.filebuffers.documentSetup">
  <participant
     class="myclasspath.MyDocumentSetup"
     extensions="myExtension">
  </participant>
</extension>
```

**MyDocumentSetup.java**

```
public class MyDocumentSetup implements IDocumentSetupParticipant {
  public void setup(IDocument document) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: The only references to this I can find are all in Eclipse internal packages which should not be used.

Comment: Have the unit test instantiate it? The extension point requires it be a public class with a public zero-argument constructor anyway.

Comment: I need the instance that is used in the eclipse instance that is started for the JUnit Plugin Tests. Maybe using a dependency injection framework is a solution.